# Powerful monitoring applications for Windows

Tags: windows, performance, latency, performance-monitor

I have been using the Windows 7 Resource Monitor lately which has proven very powerful.

[image]

One can see what disk latency any process produces and effectively disable it if not required. For example, I had noticed that certain indexing or checking utilities will produce a disk latency of at least 200ms. By disabling unneeded services it reduced to about 50ms max for most cases. This is a spectacular change.

Does anyone know of similar monitoring tools for effectively reducing latencies and resources use?

Currently, I'd be interesting in anything that goes more low level.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Windows Sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062), in particular [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), which is like task manager on steroids. Overall its a very useful set of utilities for diagnostics/troubleshooting and administration.